# There exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the number $f(x)=x^2 +5x +4$ is prime."

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

There exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the number $f(x)=x^2 +5x +4$ is prime.

I can't understand where to start.

This is what I have so far:

Let P(x) be the statement "$x^2 + 5x +4$ is prime".
Then we have $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}, P(x)$.

I built a table and I suspect that this is not true. Hence, I'm attempting to disprove this statement. Apart from doing a direct proof, I can try a contrapositive proof but I don't know how to start.

Appreciate all inputs.

Comment: When $x=0$ its 4 and when $x=1$ its 10. By continuity ...

Comment: $f(-2) = -2$ is a prime.

Comment: Note that $x^2 +5x +4=(x + 4) (x + 1)$ and so it is almost never a prime for $x \in \mathbb Z$. Only when one of the two factors is $\pm 1$; the only integer solutions are $x=-3,-2$, found by @achillehui.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is continuous, and since $f(-1)=0$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty,$$ you can show that for every $p>0$, there exists some $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=p$. You don't even have to restrict yourself to primes, the function reaches *every positive number*!

Answer (score 1):

The function goes to infinity as x goes to infinity. It is also continuous. Thus it assumes all sufficiently large real numbers. In particular it assumes all sufficiently large prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the equation 
$$
x^2 + 5x + 4 = 3
$$